# How to get a model from an .3ds to appear on a transperent background?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, 3d, 3ds

How do I make the image of the model's background transparent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way to do this in c#, I think you need to have that set in the .3ds file. Not sure how to do that however.

try: http://board.flashkit.com/board/archive/index.php/t-557898.html